# I could not understand how does the __add__ function work here?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When framing if condition for 'add_length' , isinstance has 2nd parameter 'length' but in the case of 'add_inches' the 2nd parameter is given int(integer) . I could not understand this part .why can't they both be int(integer). Help is appreciated !

```
    class Length:
        def __init__(self, feet, inches):
            self.feet = feet
            self.inches = inches
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.feet} {self.inches}'

        def __add__(self, other):
            if isinstance(other, Length):
                return self.add_length(other)
            if isinstance(other, int):
                return self.add_inches(other)
            else:
                return NotImplemented
    
        def __radd__(self, other):
            return self.__add__(other)
    
    
        def add_length(self, L):
            f = self.feet + L.feet
            i = self.inches + L.inches
            if i >= 12:
                i = i - 12
            f += 1
            return Length(f, i)
    
        def add_inches(self, inches):
            f = self.feet + inches // 12
            i = self.inches + inches % 12
            if i >= 12:
                i = i - 12
            f += 1
            return Length(f, i)
    
    
    length1 = Length(2, 10)
    length2 = Length(3, 5)
    
    print(length1 + length2)
    print(length1 + 2`
    print(length1 + 20)
    print(20 + length1)
```

Comment: ... Shouldn't `f += 1` be indented so that it is part of the conditionals' suite?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: If the clas does not behave the way you want it to you should change it.

Answer (score 0):

The first condition is checking for the scenario when two length objects are added together:

```py
length1 = Length(2, 10)
length2 = Length(3, 5)
    
print(length1 + length2)
```

The second condition is checking for the scenario when an integer is added to a length.

```py
print(length1 + 2)
print(length1 + 20)
```

The conditional calls two different methods `add_length` and `add_inches` because of how the data needs to be accessed. That is, for `add_length` it accessed via properties of the object (L). For `add_inches` it is accessed from the integer (inches).

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, this is simply the way this class is designed.

You can either add two objects from the length class together (this is the first `isinstance`) or you can add an integer in inches to the length (this is the second `isinstance`).